# Oracle SQL - How to compare the number of rows between 2 sets in the same table?

Tags: sql, oracle, compare, version, rows

in the table `security_privileges` I want to compare the number of rows for the last `version_number` with the number of rows for `version_number` BEFORE `last_update` = 01.03.2020.

I highlighted the two sets of rows that the result should identify. In the first set, there are 8 rows, in the second set there are 6 rows.

The output of what I expect from this example is right at the bottom.

Below I tried this sequel, but it didn't really work:

```
SELECT 
cur.user_id,
cur.version_number,
cur.last_update,
(cur.last_update- prv.last_update)
FROM
security_privileges prv
INNER JOIN security_privileges cur
ON cur.version_number = prv.version_number +2
```

[image: security privileges]

[image: output table]

[![output][3]][3]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a bit different approach, but still with window analytic functions:

1. at first, I'd filtered only rows you want, using `dense_rank` with `partition by user_id, case when last_update>=date'2020-03-01' then 1 else 2 end`, so this dense_rank will return 1 for all required rows and we can easily filter then using `drnk=1`:

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=b6925860bfa16d2f222d428f508c1b50

```sql
select *
from 
  (
  SELECT 
    prv.*
    ,dense_rank()
        over(
            partition by
              user_id, 
              case when last_update>=date'2020-03-01' then 1 else 2 end
            order by version_number desc
            ) as drnk
  FROM
    security_privileges prv
  ) v
where v.drnk = 1;
```

Results:

```sql
   USER_ID SECURITY_PRIVILEGE_ID VERSION_NUMBER LAST_USER_UPDATE_ID LAST_UPDATE               DRNK
---------- --------------------- -------------- ------------------- ------------------- ----------
      9867                 20011             16                9954 2020-08-31 00:00:00          1
      9867                 20059             16                9955 2020-08-31 00:00:00          1
      9867                 20003             16                9956 2020-08-31 00:00:00          1
      9867                 20069             16                9957 2020-08-31 00:00:00          1
      9867                 20004             16                9958 2020-08-31 00:00:00          1
      9867                 20046             16                9959 2020-08-31 00:00:00          1
      9867                 20003             14                9832 2017-06-28 00:00:00          1
      9867                 20059             14                9833 2017-06-28 00:00:00          1
      9867                 20046             14                9834 2017-06-28 00:00:00          1
      9867                 20004             14                9835 2017-06-28 00:00:00          1
      9867                 20045             14                9836 2017-06-28 00:00:00          1
      9867                 20002             14                9837 2017-06-28 00:00:00          1
      9867                 20011             14                9838 2017-06-28 00:00:00          1
      9867                 20069             14                9839 2017-06-28 00:00:00          1

14 rows selected.
```

2. **Second step** even easier: we just need to aggregate those rows:
   **either using conditional aggregation**: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=6467247bfde1dd978da4ce51067e3d70

```sql
select 
   user_id,
   min(version_number) version_number1,
   max(version_number) version_number2,
   count(decode(grp,1,0)) cnt1,
   count(decode(grp,2,0)) cnt2,
   listagg(decode(grp,1,security_privilege_id), ',')
      within group(order by security_privilege_id) sec_priv_ids1,
   listagg(decode(grp,2,security_privilege_id), ',')
      within group(order by security_privilege_id) sec_priv_ids2
from 
  (
  SELECT 
    prv.*
    ,case when last_update>=date'2020-03-01' then 1 else 2 end grp
    ,dense_rank()
        over(
            partition by
              user_id, 
              case when last_update>=date'2020-03-01' then 1 else 2 end
            order by version_number desc
            ) as drnk
  FROM
    security_privileges prv
  ) v
where v.drnk = 1
group  by user_id;
```

**Results**:

```
   USER_ID VERSION_NUMBER1 VERSION_NUMBER2       CNT1       CNT2 SEC_PRIV_IDS1                            SEC_PRIV_IDS2
---------- --------------- --------------- ---------- ---------- ---------------------------------------- --------------------------------------------------
      9867              14              16          6          8 20003,20004,20011,20046,20059,20069      20002,20003,20004,20011,20045,20046,20059,20069
```

**or standard aggregation** as your last screenshot shows: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=1eb736011e32754dc444c120946e8bea

```sql
select 
   user_id,
   grp,
   version_number,
   last_update,
   count(*) cnt,
   listagg(security_privilege_id, ',')
      within group(order by security_privilege_id) sec_priv_ids
from 
  (
  SELECT 
    prv.*
    ,case when last_update>=date'2020-03-01' then 1 else 2 end grp
    ,dense_rank()
        over(
            partition by
              user_id, 
              case when last_update>=date'2020-03-01' then 1 else 2 end
            order by version_number desc
            ) as drnk
  FROM
    security_privileges prv
  ) v
where v.drnk = 1
group  by user_id,grp,version_number,last_update
order by 1,2;
```

**Results:**

```
   USER_ID        GRP VERSION_NUMBER LAST_UPDATE                CNT SEC_PRIV_IDS
---------- ---------- -------------- ------------------- ---------- --------------------------------------------------
      9867          1             16 2020-08-31 00:00:00          6 20003,20004,20011,20046,20059,20069
      9867          2             14 2017-06-28 00:00:00          8 20002,20003,20004,20011,20045,20046,20059,20069
```

Full test case with sample data in CTE:

```sql
with security_privileges(user_id, security_privilege_id, version_number, last_user_update_id, last_update) as (
select 9867, 20011, 16, 9954, date'2020-08-31' from dual union all
select 9867, 20059, 16, 9955, date'2020-08-31' from dual union all
select 9867, 20003, 16, 9956, date'2020-08-31' from dual union all
select 9867, 20069, 16, 9957, date'2020-08-31' from dual union all
select 9867, 20004, 16, 9958, date'2020-08-31' from dual union all
select 9867, 20046, 16, 9959, date'2020-08-31' from dual union all

select 9867, 20011, 15, 9960, date'2020-08-13' from dual union all
select 9867, 20059, 15, 9961, date'2020-08-13' from dual union all
select 9867, 20004, 15, 9962, date'2020-08-13' from dual union all
select 9867, 20003, 15, 9963, date'2020-08-13' from dual union all
select 9867, 20046, 15, 9964, date'2020-08-13' from dual union all

select 9867, 20003, 14, 9832, date'2017-06-28' from dual union all
select 9867, 20059, 14, 9833, date'2017-06-28' from dual union all
select 9867, 20046, 14, 9834, date'2017-06-28' from dual union all
select 9867, 20004, 14, 9835, date'2017-06-28' from dual union all
select 9867, 20045, 14, 9836, date'2017-06-28' from dual union all
select 9867, 20002, 14, 9837, date'2017-06-28' from dual union all
select 9867, 20011, 14, 9838, date'2017-06-28' from dual union all
select 9867, 20069, 14, 9839, date'2017-06-28' from dual union all

select 9867, 20059, 13, 9840, date'2017-06-21' from dual union all
select 9867, 20011, 13, 9841, date'2017-06-21' from dual union all
select 9867, 20045, 13, 9842, date'2017-06-21' from dual union all
select 9867, 20003, 13, 9843, date'2017-06-21' from dual union all
select 9867, 20046, 13, 9844, date'2017-06-21' from dual union all
select 9867, 20002, 13, 9845, date'2017-06-21' from dual union all
select 9867, 20069, 13, 9846, date'2017-06-21' from dual union all

select 9867, 20069, 12, 9127, date'2017-06-02' from dual union all
select 9867, 20046, 12, 9128, date'2017-06-02' from dual union all
select 9867, 20003, 12, 9127, date'2017-06-02' from dual union all
select 9867, 20059, 12, 9128, date'2017-06-02' from dual union all
select 9867, 20011, 12, 9128, date'2017-06-02' from dual
)
select 
   user_id,
   grp,
   version_number,
   last_update,
   count(*) cnt,
   listagg(security_privilege_id, ',')
      within group(order by security_privilege_id) sec_priv_ids
from 
  (
  SELECT 
    prv.*
    ,case when last_update>=date'2020-03-01' then 1 else 2 end grp
    ,dense_rank()
        over(
            partition by
              user_id, 
              case when last_update>=date'2020-03-01' then 1 else 2 end
            order by version_number desc
            ) as drnk
  FROM
    security_privileges prv
  ) v
where v.drnk = 1
group  by user_id,grp,version_number,last_update
order by 1,2;
```

Comment: Sayan, you are golden, mate! That's exactly what I needed! Outstanding! Many thanks!

Comment: Great, thanks, so please mark the answer as a correct one if it works for you :)

Comment: Sure mate, already marked it:-) One thing I wanted to change - where can I include only users where version_number1 != version_number2? Apparently putting this at the bottom after the WHERE clause won't work.

Comment: @Skywalker are you talking about conditional aggregation or standard one?

Comment: @Skywalker in case of conditional aggregation you just need to add `having` clause: `having min(version_number) != max(version_number)`

Comment: I think it worked fine with the conditional aggregation:-) I still try to get my head around the first statement where you use 'DENSE_RANK'. So where does the partition into 2 sets happen? For example, I have a user that was last updated on 13.08.2020. When I run the statement it shows 2 sets- one for the update on 13.08.2020 and the other on 28.06.2017. Also, what's the purpose of 'drnk=1'? This is all correctly shown. I just want to understand how this is done.

Comment: further to clarify, how do you create two partitions with the same drnk =1? For this particular user, I have many other updates in the past, but here only two sets of data are selected. Which is of course correct:-)

Comment: `partition by user_id, when last_update>=date'2020-03-01' then 1 else 2 end` split data set into 2 groups per each user_id: one for those rows that before 2020-03-01 and second one >=2020-03-01, then dense_rank sorts each row in group and set 1 for last rows by date.

Comment: so drnk=1 filter only last row in each group

Comment: Makes more sense now, thanks:-) I tried to subtract the SELECT statement cnt1-cnt2.I tried this, but it didn't work: 'SUM (count(decode(grp, 1, 0))) - SUM(count(decode(grp, 2, 0))) AS DIFF'

Comment: I still have a hard time understanding DENSE_RANK and partitioning. I thought that the rank resets and starts again from 1 only when the clause after PARTITION_BY changes. In this case, it's 'user_id'. So if you don't specify 'where v.drnk = 1' at the end of the statement, the rank will change even if the user_id is the same...It will be great if you can clarify this for me.

Comment: Also, I wonder why the rank doesn't change to 2 when the version number changes? I see that after ORDER BY is the version_number.

Comment: @Skywalker first of all, plese show what exactly have you tried and doesn't work

Comment: "I thought that the rank resets and starts again from 1 only when the clause after PARTITION_BY changes. In this case, it's user_id" - not only user_id, but `case when...` too

Comment: " I wonder why the rank doesn't change to 2 when the version number changes" - it changes...

Comment: I just added the output of the first part of the sequel, for one specific user. You can see that the partition splits in two. One has version 19, the other version 14. However, drnk stays the same, i.e. it's 1. How is this achieved?

Comment: @Skywalker please provide exact code, results and more detailed question. for example on dbfiddle

Comment: Hi, I just pulled from dbfiddle the output from your first sequel. Have a look at the attached picture just at the bottom of the original message. The version number changes from 14 to 16, but DRNK stays at 1.  How do you achieve that? Is it the CASE statement after PARTITION BY? Below the sequel

Comment: select *
from 
  (
  SELECT 
    prv.*
    ,dense_rank()
        over(
            partition by
              user_id, 
              case when last_update>=date'2020-03-01' then 1 else 2 end
            order by version_number desc
            ) as drnk
  FROM
    security_privileges prv
  ) v
where v.drnk = 1;

Answer (score 2):

You can use window functions and conditional aggregation.  The inner query calculates the maximum version number overall and before the specified date:

```
select user_id, max_vn, max_vn_pre,
       sum(case when version_number = max_vn then 1 else 0 end) as max_vn_cnt,
       sum(case when version_number = max_vn_pre then 1 else 0 end) as max_vn_pre_cnt
from (select sp.*,
             max(version_number) over (partition by user_id) as max_vn,
             max(case when last_update < date '2020-03-01' then version_number end) over (partition by user_id) as max_vn_pre
      from security_privileges sp
     ) sp
group by user_id, max_vn, max_vn_pre;
```

This assumes that you want the results per user_id.  If not, just remove the `partition by` in the two windowing clauses.